# Error 404 When Run The Upload Service Method in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload, fiddler

Below is the coding for the upload service method,

```
public static string base64Decode(string document)
   {

    byte[] toDecodeByte = Convert.FromBase64String(document);

    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    System.Text.Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();

    int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(toDecodeByte, 0, toDecodeByte.Length);

    char[] decodedChar = new char[charCount];
    utf8Decode.GetChars(toDecodeByte, 0, toDecodeByte.Length, decodedChar, 0);
    string result = new String(decodedChar);
    return result;
}
```

I'm not really sure whether this code is enough to upload file actually. I've refer to a lot of websites, but it doesn't really answer my question. There's is no error inside this code.

Below is the coding for the WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "assignmentFile",
                routeTemplate: "api/assignmentFile/{document}",
                defaults: new { Controller = "AssignmentFile", document = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I've tested it using Fiddler:
POST
api/assignmentFile/IT_LabExercise.pdf
content-type: application/json
Request Body:
{ 'document':'IT_LabExercise.pdf', 'document':'IT_LabExercise.pdf'}
and the result shows error 404. Anyone can help me with this? I really have no idea already. T_T

To be honestly, I don't really understand the coding. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Aside from anything else, the first method is a very longwinded way of writing `return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(document))`. Mind you, if the document is a PDF file, you shouldn't be trying to decode the binary data as if it's UTF-8 anyway...

Comment: Opps, really? How can I make improvement to it? Yea, my document including PDF file as well. I refer to a lot of website, but not really get the concept. I'm actually trying to refer to this site :http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2012/02/23/more-about-rest-file-upload-download-service-with-asp-net-web-api-and-windows-phone-background-file-transfer.aspx , anyway, it's complicated for me. I got no idea now. I'm actually using the entity framework for it.

Comment: You need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits. May I know what is this?? What Approved?? What 2k reputation?? what suggested edits?? Can anyone help me?? T_T

Comment: Btw, I have found solution for this by editing the code to be like this:

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges